# Image color ruined while resizing it using imagecopyresampled

Tags: php, image, gd

After uploading images to my website, the images are being resized. I'm using the `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagecopyresampled` functions. I've noticed that the color is not the same as in the original image.

Here you can see the difference. You can see the image from flicker with the currect colors and behind the image from my website. 
[image: Example]

**The original image:** https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5754/23693488109_74c67f012a_k.jpg

**After rsizing:** https://www.isrart.co.il/img/uploads/art/viewer/big/photo-2b971e861c7aa2c57b8f7667ec666c3d.jpg

Here is my PHP code:

```
    $type = @getImageSize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])[2];
    switch ($type) { 
        case 1 : 
            $img = imageCreateFromGif($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); 
        break; 
        case 2 : 
            $img = imageCreateFromJpeg($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); 
        break; 
        case 3 : 
            $img = imageCreateFromPng($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); 
        break; 
        case 6 : 
            $img = imageCreateFromBmp($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); 
        break; 
    }    

    $orig_width = imagesx($img);
    if($orig_width < $width)
        return $img;

    $orig_height = imagesy($img);

    $height = (($orig_height * $width) / $orig_width);

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $orig_width, $orig_height);

    imagejpeg($new_image, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/img/uploads/" . $path, 100);
```

Comment: di you go through the comments , it may help http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Comment: Please post actual original and resampled images - rather than a picture of them.

Comment: @zod was there one that stood out to you? I browsed the comments from the manual page but only a couple *possibly* relate to this issue, and most are so many years old that their continued validity would be questionable.

Comment: This is because of the compression - even at 100% quality its going to be passed through compression because of how jpegs work - they are not lossless. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345605/php-imagecopyresampled-poor-quality - please review this thread.  You should consider moving to PNG for this as PNG is a lossless format.  You can also review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421200/improve-quality-of-php-gd-generated-images for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your original image has a 560-byte ICC profile associated with it, whereas your resampled image does not.

You can extract the profile from the original image using ImageMagick like this:

```
convert orig.jpg profile.icm
```

You can see it here if I difference the two files:

[image]

I note that, if I resample your original image at the command-line with ImageMagick, like this:

```
convert orig.jpg -resize 1110x1570! myresampled.jpg
```

then the ICC profile is carried forward. I can check like this:

```
identify -verbose orig.jpg myresampled.jpg | grep -i profile

  Profiles:
    Profile-icc: 560 bytes
  Profiles:
    Profile-icc: 560 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use it in PHP?

Comment: It's pretty easy, examples here... http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php

Comment: Is there any way to do this using PHP's GD library, without installing ImageMagick? The original question doesn't reference ImageMagick and in general I am loathe to go with a solution that requires installation of a new package unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Extending upon @Mark Setchell's answer:

Use this file to copy original image's ICC profile to resized image's ICC profile. Than problem is resolved. It is a single file without any dependencies.

https://github.com/slavicv/jpeg-icc/blob/master/class.jpeg_icc.php

For my use case I edited file, so it works with images in memory not using filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's a PNG file and there is an information chunk called "gAMA" in it.  It's kind of a gamma correction thing, some viewers use it, some don't.  When you load your image, the GD library ignores this information.  But Imagick should do the trick:

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageproperties.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: the original image is a JPG :S

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the compressed image looks dull compared to original is because of its colour format. Original uses 4:4:4 chroma sub-sampling while the compressed one uses 4:2:0 sub-sampling. This causes loss in colour information.

[image: Used mediainfo tool to read image metadata]

To overcome this, we can do this scaling using ffmpeg or avconv and that can be executed from shell in PHP.

I produced good quality scaled image using avconv with following 2 commands.

```
avconv -i Input.jpg -pix_fmt yuvj444p -vf scale=1110:1570 Output.yuv

avconv -y -s 1110x1570 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv444p -i Output.yuv Output.jpg
```